# Animation between WatchKit Interface controllers

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch app, which consists of several interface controllers. I found 2 possible ways to switch between the various controllers:

1. Segue: either programmatically or defined in the interface builder
2. WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers

I like the latter most because in this case the watch does not shows (and allows) to close the active  interface controller via the top left button (with the label "close" or "cancel"). Unfortunately the switch via reloadRootControllers is *hard* and without nice animation. Thus my question is, is there another way to show and interface controller (without those ugly button on the top left)? Or is it possible to make nice animations when calling reloadRootControllers?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm just trying to solve this now.